# Is it possible to store GLTF on MongDB Atlas

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, gltf

Is it possible to easily store files such as gltf/glb into a MongoDB Atlas database and pull them down instead to a React web app. Preferably originally storing the files on the database using the MongoDB Compass program (so testing of pulling down and using the files can be done).

Thank you for any help happy to provide more explanation/details.